# How to finish multiple activities on a button click?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am implementing android application which is on web service. I'm creating login `Activity A` then homepage `Activity B` and so on.

Suppose there are A, B, C, D and E etc. activities. I'm creating a home button in `Activity E` and by clicking on that `Activity E, D and C` should finish and home `Activity B` should resume.

How can I implement that?

> A > B > C > D > E > back button in E
>   Activity > B.

Comment: It is a hardware back button press or is it a custom `Button` press?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag.

In essence it does the following. If the `Activity` this `Intent` is directed to is paused in your current back stack then it will resume it and clear the stack above it destroying all the activities in the stack above it.

**UPDATE:** In response to Jason Hanley.

Thanks for mentioning it. The documentation of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` covers that example. If you don't want `Activity B` to be recreated but just passed the new `Intent` then you should define its launch mode as `singleTop`.

Comment: If B's `launchMode` is not `singleTop`, you should also use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) if you want B to resume.

Answer (score 3):

Use onActivityResult method in chain . Start closing with the outermost activity-E when pressed on home , then check for its result and accordingly close activity-D and so on .