# StartActivity and Multiple Instances

Tags: android, back

I'm a little puzzled by how activities work. If I do a `StartActivity()` by pressing a button, and then I press the Back button to get back to the original activity, and then I press the button again to do the same `StartActivity()`, are there two instances of the new activity? I know `onCreate()` is called each time, so is the first instance orphaned (presumably eventually Garbage Collected)?

Should I always ensure that `finish()` is called (via the Back button), just to be safe? I'm not sure what the protocol is here.

Comment: Have you override the `onKeyDown` with processing the `KEYCODE_BACK`, Or you press the button quickly which cause two activity started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Android development site ([source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)):

> An application usually consists of multiple activities that are loosely bound to each other. Typically, one activity in an application is specified as the "main" activity, which is presented to the user when launching the application for the first time. Each activity can then start another activity in order to perform different actions. **Each time a new activity starts, the previous activity is stopped, but the system preserves the activity in a stack (the "back stack"). When a new activity starts, it is pushed onto the back stack and takes user focus. The back stack abides to the basic "last in, first out" queue mechanism, so, when the user is done with the current activity and presses the BACK key, it is popped from the stack (and destroyed) and the previous activity resumes. (The back stack is discussed more in the Tasks and Back Stack document.)**

(bolding by me)

And this page is especially interesting to understand the way it works in details:

[Tasks and back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: On a related question, is there a way to pop off all but the first activity on the stack, ie, jump all the way to the "home" activity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193494/how-to-finish-multiple-activities-on-a-button-click   -   Personally, I use onActivityResult chaining (start your activities with StartActivityForResult, and set corresponding status in onActivityResult, so you can finish them all when you need to)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs,

> `public void onBackPressed ()` Since: API Level 5
>
> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

the default implementation on pressing back key will call `finish()` to the current Activity