# How to finish multiple activities at once in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have my Activity flows like this ACTIVITY A -> ACTIVITY B -> ACTIVITY C -> ACTIVITY D. When the user is on Activity D and click a button called exit, the application should go back to Activity B and finish the Activities C and D. How can I do that?

NOTE : ACTIVITY B and ACTIVITY D are the same class but different instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to finish multiple activities on a button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193494/how-to-finish-multiple-activities-on-a-button-click)

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410295/finish-parent-and-current-activity-in-android

Comment: mmm you might be able to call finish() on activity C and the if you press back on D it will go to B?.

Answer (score 4):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set `android:noHistory` as **true** for Activity B, C and D.  set it as **false** for Activity A (actually, the default is false).

Demo:

```
<activity android:name=".xx.xx.ActivityA" 
    android:noHistory="false"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".xx.xx.ActivityB" 
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
</activity>        

<activity android:name=".xx.xx.ActivityC" 
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".xx.xx.ActivityD" 
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
</activity>
```

For the exit `Button`:

```
exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite complicated solution, but allows to fully manipulate backstack. Basically create your own "backstack" in you `Application`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Activity> runningActivities = new HashSet<>();

    onCreate() {
        // ...
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                runningActivities.add(activity);
            }
            @Override public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
                runningActivities.remove(activity);
            }
        });
    }

    public void killActivities(Set<Class<?>> activitiesToRemove) {
        for (Activity stackActivity : runningActivities) {
            if (activitiesToRemove.contains(stackActivity.getClass())) {
                stackActivity.finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call something like this in you ActivityD:

`((MyApplication)getApplication()).killActivities(ActivityD.class, ActivityC.class)`

You can use `Map` instead of `Set` if class isn't only specifier necessary to determine which activity should be removed...

Please corret me if there is something wrong with my solution, but it seems like there should be no leaks and no boilerplate in your activities

**Edit - Kotlin version:**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    private val runningActivities = mutableSetOf<Activity>()

    
    override fun onCreate() {
        // ...
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
            override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
                runningActivities.add(activity)
            }
            override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
                runningActivities.remove(activity)
            }
        })
    }

    fun killActivities(activitiesToRemove: Set<Class<Activity>>) {
        runningActivities.forEach { activity ->
            if (activitiesToRemove.contains(activity.javaClass)) {
                activity.finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
When you back from activity D and go to activity A then you need to use these code.
 1. First create the instance of all activity using this code.

Activity A{

}

Activity B{
public static Activity activityB;

oncreate(){
activityB=this;
}
Activity C{
public static Activity activityC;

oncreate(){
activityC=this;
}

Activity D{

}

2. Please call this method on back press in Activity D

private finishActivity(){
Clear the instance of middle activity.
 B.activityB.finish();
 C.activityC.finish();
  finish();
}
```

Comment: use static variable as Activity is very dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your ActivityD.class

```
 finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not working with 5 Activities it goes back up to the initial activity.

Answer (score -2):

Best and full proof way of implementing this is create the Application class which extends android.app.Application and there just maintain your list of opened activity's instances.

Next is mention your created Application class name into `<application>` within the AndroidManifest.xml

And then whenever you want you can destroy the opened activities.