# How to close 2 activities with single action

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-finish

There are 3 activities A, B, C.

A -> B -> C with button

A <------ C with button that close C and B?

```
A -> B

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }

B -> C

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }

B -> A

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       finish();
   }

C -> B

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       finish();
   }
```

How to back to A from C with button that close C and B?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198055/how-to-finish-multiple-activities-at-once-in-android. You can also use `startActivityForResult` for this case just send result back to Activity B from Activity C and it will close and now you will be On Activity A . You can Also use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` [Like This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities).

Comment: ever considered using fragments instead of activities?

Comment: ```Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP``` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **finish()** for this.

B -> C

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);

    startActivity(intent);
    
    finish(); //Solution
}
```

**Note:** You can also use [launch modes](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959).

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult for A -> B and B -> C then override below method in C

```js
override fun onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK)
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

now in B override below method

```js
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) return

        when (requestCode) {
            YoutIntentCodeWhenYouGoToC -> {
                setResult(RESULT_OK)
                onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you are in A. And if you press a back button then it wont show B or C screen.